# How to toggle the opacity of Elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I have a div which has 14 child divs with some content. Now what I need is that, onload it should display all the 14 divs with opacity = 1, but when I mouse over one of them, the opacity of others should reduce by 50%. Only the current one should have the full opacity. Similarly when I move my mouse over another div now, then except the current one, opacity of other divs should be reduced by 50%.

How can I do so using javascript and I don't want to use any library (jquery).

**Update : Got it working! :)**

```
/*onmouseover*/
function showCurrentDimOthers(el) {
        var otherElements = document.getElementById("see_all_content_holder").childNodes;
        for (var o = 0; o < otherElements.length; o++) {
            otherElements[o].style.opacity = 0.5;
            otherElements[o].style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=5)';
        }

        el.style.opacity = 1.0;
        el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=10)';
    }

/*onmouseout*/
function dimCurrent(el) {
        el.style.opacity = 0.5;
        el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=5)';

    }
```

Comment: Are you even familiar with css and javascript? I think jQuery is a good choice for beginners.

Comment: @Jivings, what I did was, onmouseover of each child div, I am calling a function which gets all the child divs and sets there opacity to 0.5 and then I am setting the opacity of the current div using 'this' keyword to have the opacity to 1. Then onmouseout I am setting the opacity of current div to 50%. Still I am getting some undesired results. I am updating the question with my code. Please check.

Comment: @rufus and Jivings, thanks for making an effort to help me :) I appreciate it. I think, I was lost somewhere when I was coding it, it was so simple, got it in a blink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so complicated? From what I see, CSS is enough for this:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ul>

ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkAyb/

Comment: @Yoshi, cool solution :) I will mark your answer also as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the opacity this way:

```
document.getElementById('someid').style.opacity = '0.5';
```

Use onmouseover and onmouseout events for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

An idea I didn't try:

1. Give each div an id, e.g. "div-1", "div-2"
2. Store all of them in an array.
3. Listen to onmouseover event, loop the array and change the opacity of all the elements that are in the array that are different to the current Id.
4. Listen to onmouseout event and revert all the opacity to 1.

If it's not clear enough let me know.

Comment: Got your solution, it will alos work perfectly, though i got my own code working which I have updated in the post now. thanks for the alternate solution